# VSCode - Maven.archetype.generate fails

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code

I get the below error message when I try to run the command in VSCode.

```
Command "maven.archetype.generate" fails. Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

As far as I can see, I have all plugins/extensions but cannot work out why it won't work. I found this but still cannot get it to work, however I can run apps for files created before I updated VSCode to version 1.32.1. I just cannot create new ones.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like a bug.

> Are you running the commands without any workspace or folder open?
>   Open a folder first, see if the issue still exists. If it's gone, I
>   suppose it's because of a potential NPE which is fixed by PR #276 but
>   not released yet. Please let me know the result.

It worked for me!

See more: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/277#issuecomment-473166245

Answer (score -1):

From command line, type in:

```
mvn --version
```

to see if Maven is installed properly.

You need maven and jdk installed for maven to work.

Check out the “Before you begin” here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_create-the-program

What is probably happening is that you do not have Maven or JDK installed, or you have not set the system variables properly. These installations are not the same as the plugins/extensions found in Visual Studio Code. These are in addition to that.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have to install jdk and maven to your system. and you have to set system variables also. Then check it again.

Comment: This answer is not clear at all.